# use a if condition to find which page redirects to current page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am redirecting to sendmessage page from group page and user page. In the sendmessage server side code how can I find which page redirected to send message page. since I have different code for each page i need to use a if condition to determine it. how to code the if condition.

From user page

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="SendButton" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/Message.jpg" Enabled="True" Width="" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("Email", "SendMessage.aspx?Email={0}") %>'></asp:ImageButton>
```

From Group page

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="SendButton" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/Message.jpg" Enabled="True" Width="" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# Eval("groupname", "SendMessage.aspx?=groupname={0}") %>'></asp:ImageButton>
```

I tried this but it didn't work

```
string url = Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri;
        if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("SendMessage.aspx?GroupName"))
{}
```

[url= http://localhost:48996/SurelyK/SendMessage.aspx?GroupName=iCam]

Comment: In what namespace is Request found here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples! HTTP provides a header which your browser may (or may not) fill in, all you need to do is check it on sendmessage page.  It can be accessed via:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

Now do a simple test based on the expected pages.

There are also a number of other options such as adding variables to the GET request which can also be accessed on the next page, but the above should suffice.

Comment: Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
        if ( MyUrl == "Groups.aspx"){}      is it like this

Comment: No, you'll need a .toString to get the MyUrls string representation

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL of the previous page via `Request.UrlReferrer` inside the sendmessage page

try and check like this:

```
if(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath=="/Group.aspx")
    ;//do something
else if(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath=="/Page.aspx")
    ;//do something else
```

Comment: Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
        if ( MyUrl == "Groups.aspx"){}      is it like this

Answer (score 0):

You can do a check against the UrlReferrer like this:

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.ToLower().Contains("groups.aspx"))
{
     //logic
}
```